# How to Dispose DI Injection chain from main instance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, idisposable, tinyioc

https://github.com/int6/CoiniumServ/blob/develop/src/CoiniumServ/Pools/Pool.cs

this is my pool class. i want that when i dispose the class. all dependencies should be stop working and dispose it self.

i tried and implement idisposable to all dependency to dispose but it doesnt work.

i also implement a thread to run function in thread and destroy it with thread abort. that also doesnt work.

is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Try to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

A component should **not** dispose any injected dependencies. The main reasons for this are:

1. that component didn't create them, and therefore has no idea whether those dependencies should be disposed or not.
2. consumers shouldn't even be aware that dependencies are disposable.

It is very common for a component to depend on a service with a longer lifestyle. In case the consuming component disposes that dependency, the application will break, because the dependency cannot longer be used, while it is configured to be used. Here's a simple example:

```
// Singleton
private static readonly IRepository<User> repository = new UserRepository();

public IController CreateController(Type controllerType) {
    if (controllerType == typeof(UserController)) {
        return new UserController(repository);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This example contains a singleton `UserRepository` and a transient `UserController`. For each request, an new `UserController` is created (just picture an ASP.NET MVC application, and this will start to make sense). If the `UserController` would dispose the `UserRepository`, the next request would get a `UserController` that would depend on an already disposed `UserRepository`. This would obviously bad.

But besides this, `IRepository<T>` should **not** implement `IDisposable`. Implementing `IDisposable` means that the abstraction is leaking implementation details and therefor violates the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), that states:

> Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on
>   abstractions.

Implementing `IDisposable` on an abstraction only makes sense if you are absolutely 100% sure that *all* implementations of that abstraction that you'll ever make need to dispose itself. But this hardly ever is the case. Just imagine having a `FakeRepository<T>` implementation in your unit tests. Such fake implementation never needs disposal and therefore not all implementations need disposal and you're leaking implementation details.

This simply means that you should move the `IDisposable` interface *to the implementation*. For instance:

```
public interface IRepository<T> { }

public class UserRepository : IRepository<User>, IDisposable { }
```

Note that having the `IDisposable` interface on an abstraction, while not all consumers are expected to call `Dispose` also means you are violating the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) that states that:

> no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

Advantage of this is that it becomes impossible for consuming components (such as the `UserController`) to accidentally call `Dispose()` and with that possibly break the system.

Another advantage is that since components don't need to dispose their dependencies, for most components there will be no disposal logic left, making the system considerably simpler and more maintainable.